# Call Process.Start once and subsequent calls without starting new process

Tags: c#

I have a c# method that sets the brightness of all monitors using a third-party executable.I call it using the method below. The problem is that I need to call this executable with different parameters to change the brightness. But my code creates a new process each time I call SetBrightness. How does one use an exiting process that is already running, and pass different parameters to execute it again? I don't see any method inthe Process class that makes this easy.

Edit: When I run this exe using the command line, the process stays open in the Windows System Tray, and I see the process is running in Task Manager. When I run my code, however, I sometimes see two instances of the exe in Task Manager. So I guess what I'm trying to do is always call the same instance but with different parameters. Restarting the exe every time is not an option because it takes too long to start up each time.

```
    public bool SetBrightness(short monitorStartIndex, short monitorEndIndex, short brightness)
    {
        // Construct the parameter string used by the tool so that it updates all monitors in one call.
        // Example "1 b75 2 b75" will set brightness to 75 for monitors 1 and 2.
        StringBuilder arguments = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = monitorStartIndex; i <= monitorEndIndex; i++)
        {
            arguments.Append(i).Append(" ");
            arguments.Append(string.Format("b{0}", brightness)).Append(" ");
        }

        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1]);
        var final = Path.Combine(path, "External Assemblies\\ClickMonitorDDC_3_9.exe");

        var p = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = final,
                Arguments = arguments.ToString(),
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            }
        };

        try
        {
            p.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Error while changing the brightness using ClickMonitorDDC_3_9.exe. Inner Exception : " + e.Message);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why not store the process as a static variable, then end the process everytime you call the function at the start? Edit: or alternatively, if the process is setup to receive more data after its already running, send it new instructions each time. That's the best answer I can give without more information.

Comment: You say you need to call this exe with different parameters to chage the brightness. So unless you don't actually need to do that, won't you need to start it up again as a new process in order to actually start the exe again? Am I missing something?

Comment: I edited my question with more information. Hope this helps. How do I send in new instructions?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the WaitForExit method available in the Process class. If you attempt to use the third-party executable from the command line using the same type of parameters as you have in your code, it should return to the prompt as it is setting the parameters and exiting.  You would just call your method whenever you want to change the brightness and wait until it's set and exit out.

Change your code as seen below:

```
 try
    {
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit()
    }
```

Comment: How does this allow me to rerun the executable with different parameters? I don't understand.

Comment: When using the p.WaitForExit the process basically gets closed.  You would then call your SetBrightness method again. I don't see how you would change the existing parameters on the running process as the process method is using start arguments that get fired when you run a new instance of the processs.  This will at least prevent from leaving tons of open processes, but you won't be able to change the existing process